# Having Issues with drop down menu and display

Tags: jquery, html, css, mysql

I have managed to work through and get this far but having issues with getting a second drop down box to display the info needed from the mysql database and then add it to the database along with other info.

Errors : the second drop cdown menu will show data but will not display selected item

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\clock\pages\Work.php on line 206

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\clock\pages\Work.php on line 221

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Jobs Plus Door Clock</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
<link href="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
<link href="../vendor/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<style type="text/css">
    .aah {
        color: white
    }

    .aah:hover {
        color: white
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<body style="overflow:auto;">

<div id="wrapper">

<div class="navbar-default " role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="side-menu">

            <li>
                <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Door Clock </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Work.php"><i class="fa fa-hourglass fa-fw"></i> Work Clock</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i>Manage Employees<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                    <li>
                        <a href="add.php">Add Employee</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="employees.php">Employees</a>
                    </li>


                </ul>
                <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
            </li>
            auto
            <li>
                <a href=""><i class="fa fa-hourglass fa-fw"></i> Back To Job Time</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="time.php"><i class="fa fa-hourglass fa-fw"></i> Hours Worked</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="export.php">Export</a>
            </li>


        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-static-side -->


<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3 class="page-header">Dashboard (TODAY) <?= date("Y-m-d") ?></h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php
                        if (isset($_POST[ 'add' ])) {
                            include_once 'dbconnect.php';
                            $id = $_POST[ 'employee' ];
                            if (mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `timing` (`employee_id`,start,date) VALUES "
                                . "(" . $id . ",NOW(),CURDATE())")) {
                                echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
                            Time Added
                        </div>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                            Error while adding
                        </div>';
                            }
                        }


                        if (isset($_POST[ 'end' ])) {
                            include_once 'dbconnect.php';
                            $id = $_POST[ 'id' ];
                            if (mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE  `timing` set end=NOW() where id=" . $id)) {
                                echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
                            Time Stopped
                        </div>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                            Error while stopping
                        </div>';
                            }
                        }

                        ?>
                        <form method="post">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <label>
                                    <select name="employee" class="form-control">
                                        <?php
                                    include_once 'dbconnect.php';
                                    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from employees ORDER BY name ");
                                    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                                        $name = $row2[ 'name' ];
                                        $id = $row2[ 'id' ];
                                        echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $name . '</option>';
                                        }

                                        ?>

                                    </select>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">

                                <form method="post">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                                        <label>
                                            <select name="code_id" class="form-control">
                                                <?php
                                            include_once 'dbconnect.php';
                                            $result3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from codetiming  ");
                                            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
                                                $name1 = $row2[ 'name' ];
                                                $id = $row2[ 'id' ];
                                                echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $name1 . '</option>';
                                                }

                                                ?>

                                            </select>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6">


                                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="add" value="Set Time"/>
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type=name="add" value="Clock All Out"/>
                                        </label>


                                    </div>
                                </form>

                            </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <?php


            $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start, end) 
       as `difference` from timing where date = CURDATE()");
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $empolyee_id = $row[ 'employee_id' ];
                $id = $row[ 'id' ];
                $start = date_create($row[ 'start' ]);
                $start = date_format($start, "Y-m-d h:i:s A");
                $code_id = $row[ 'name1' ];


                if (!empty($row[ 'end' ])) {
                    $end = date_create($row[ 'end' ]);
                    $end = date_format($end, "Y-m-d h:i:s A");
                } else {
                    $end = $row[ 'end' ];
                }

                $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from employees where id=" . $empolyee_id);
                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
                $name = $row2[ 'name' ];

                $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from codetiming where id=" . $code_id);
                $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
                $name1 = $row2[ 'name1' ];
                echo '<center><h4><b><h1 style="font-size:200%;">' . $name . '</h1></b></h4></center><hr/>';
                echo '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <center><h2>' . $start . ' (' . $name1 . ')</h2></center>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>';

                if (!empty($end)) {
                    echo '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <center><h2>' . $end . ' (' . $name1 . ')</h2></center>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>';
                } else {
                    echo '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <center><h2><form method="post"><input type="submit" name="end" value="OUT" /><input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '"/></form></h2></center>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>';
                }
            }
            ?>


        </div>

        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
<script src="../vendor/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/morrisjs/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="../data/morris-data.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```

I have managed to get the Name and start time and end time and date to work and make entry into the database but having issues with the second drop down menu displaying and adding info needed.

Comment: Based on the error message, you have an error with one of your SQL queries.  The error is stating that one of your `$result` variables is a boolean and `mysqli_query` will only return a boolean (`false`) if the query fails.

Comment: I would suggest that add your php code also and tag this post to php. @Kyle is right your query is not working

Answer (score 0):

May be your query is failed or returning a **False**. You want to use `mysqli_error()` for see what actually happen. Put below code for check :

```
if (!$result2) {
    printf("Error: ", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}
```